# Centering an element with dynamic width & having an element next to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't really describe the situation so here's what I want.

[image: aww]

`< Today >` (including arrows) should be centered. And because `Today` can be changed, it has dynamic width.

The calendar icon should have been next to `< Today >` element, having certain margin.

Can it be achieved with pure HTML and CSS? or should I do some javascript thing?

Comment: Could you make a fiddle or post a link to that page?

Comment: @AlessandroMaglioccola Sorry my bad. That image is what I got as PSD.

Comment: So you haven't tried anything at all yet?

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol Kindly share what have you tried at least

Comment: I would've done that if I had some hint, at least. But I got stuck even before trying anything.

Comment: What can you try if you don't even know how to start?

Comment: Learning the basics of HTML and CSS wouldn't be a bad start

Comment: well how about you try "googling" exactly what you want. There are plenty ways to achieve this and also many topics about this on stackoverflow. Or try to explain why your request is different to others, already existing topics.

Comment: This is not a simple thing IMHO... Did you even read my question thoroughly?

Comment: I provided an example that would fit your needs. It's just a matter of implementing it into your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `< Today >` in a container, then give that container a `width` of `auto`, and a left & right `margin` of `auto` so it centers it.

### HTML

```
<div class="yourparentdiv">
  <div class="container>
    < Today >
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You could then add the calendar by adding another `div` and using the `absolute` `position` and set it `relative` to `.container`. Alternatively, you could add it using `:after` CSS selector for the `#today` `div`.

Comment: I wrote in the question that `< Today >` has dynamic width so absolute positioning the icon doesn't work...

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol Yes it does. The `absolute` position would be based off the calculated width of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to achieve this.

Margin: auto can work.
Table/tablecell classes
inline-block element with text-align:center in parent...

Hard to guess what will do it for you. Provide some code and try google.

Comment: lol did you even read my question? The thing is that the calendar icon should be next to something which should be centered solely without considering the width of the icon itself.

Comment: just start centering the "today" dynamically and the rest should be a piece of cake.
E.g. put the calendar into an afterlement.

Anyway nobody can tell you what would be best when you provide no code at all.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achived using `css flex boxes`. Please go through the following tutorial to learn more.

[tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)